# How to avoid unexpected memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory

I just write a small MemoryHook library with c++ and use as preload.But when I run the test every time,there is a large amount of memory allocated,the size is 72704.
The usage is like this:
    LD_PRELOAD=./libPreload.so ./XXX

I try to find all related library in ldd  list, but no size is 72704.I removed other information and only kept the size, but also has this problem.

My initialize code:

```
    static void TraceInitialize()
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        fprintf( stderr, "call TraceInitialize\n" );      
#endif
        pthread_mutex_lock( &s_mutexInit );
        if ( s_status == TS_INITIALIZED ) { pthread_mutex_unlock( &s_mutexInit ); return; }

        s_status = TS_INITIALIZING;

        MemoryManager::initialize();

        s_pRealMalloc       = (FUNC_MALLOC)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
        s_pRealCalloc       = (FUNC_CALLOC)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "calloc");
        s_pRealRealloc      = (FUNC_REALLOC)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "realloc");
        s_pRealMemalign     = (FUNC_MEMALIGN)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "memalign");
        s_pRealValloc       = (FUNC_VALLOC)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "valloc");
        s_pRealFree         = (FUNC_FREE)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "free");

        assert( !( NULL == s_pRealMalloc || NULL == s_pRealCalloc || NULL == s_pRealRealloc || 
                    NULL == s_pRealMemalign || NULL == s_pRealValloc || NULL == s_pRealFree ) );

        s_status = TS_INITIALIZED;

       // printMap();

        pthread_mutex_unlock( &s_mutexInit );
    }
```

and trace malloc call:

```
 static int s_no_hook = 0;
 void* TraceMalloc( size_t size )
 {  
      if ( s_status == TS_INITIALIZING ) return mockMemory::_mockMalloc( size );

      if ( s_status != TS_INITIALIZED )  TraceInitialize();

      void* p = _impMalloc( size, __sync_fetch_and_add( &s_no_hook, 1 ) );
      __sync_fetch_and_sub( &s_no_hook, 1 );
      return p;
  }
```

When I test a demo problem just has empty main function.I expect not memory unfree but the real output is:

```
++++++++++++++ unfreed addr: 0x55cc4ae22260, size: 72704, serial: 1 ++++++++++++++
backtrace:
./libPreLoad.so(_ZN11MemoryTrace13MemoryManager14storeBacktraceEPNS0_11tagUnitNodeE+0x28)[0x7f62fd6cceba]
./libPreLoad.so(_ZN11MemoryTrace13MemoryManager10appendUnitEPvmb+0x9f)[0x7f62fd6ccbb7]
./libPreLoad.so(_ZN11MemoryTrace10_impMallocEmb+0x52)[0x7f62fd6cd4cb]
./libPreLoad.so(_ZN11MemoryTrace11TraceMallocEm+0x58)[0x7f62fd6cd286]
./libPreLoad.so(malloc+0x18)[0x7f62fd6cc812]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x8f416)[0x7f62fd1cd416]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x10733)[0x7f62fd9e0733]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x10ca)[0x7f62fd9d10ca]
++++++++++++++ end ++++++++++++++
```

With no backtrace, the output is:

```
++++++++++++++ unfreed addr: 0x55f799c8e260, size: 72704, serial: 0 ++++++++++++++
backtrace:
++++++++++++++ end ++++++++++++++
```

And there is an additional problem that cannot count the memory release of static global variables.I can't find a suitable time to do this,even with **attribute** ((destructor(101))).

Comment: Find a tool to decode addresses like `libstdc++.so.6(+0x8f416)` into symbol names. Maybe `addr2line -f`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just fix this problem now.This memory is automatically applied by libstdc++ at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big allocation which you are seeing is the `C++ STL`. As asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692117/why-is-c-initial-allocation-so-much-larger-than-cs) by [rerumu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9419412/rerumu) and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56692435/8548828) by [Nikos C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856199/nikos-c)

> The heap usage comes from the C++ standard library. It allocates
>   memory for internal library use on startup. If you don't link against
>   it, there should be zero difference between the C and C++ version.
>   With GCC and Clang, you can compile the file with:
>
> ```
>  g++ -Wl,--as-needed main.cpp
> ```
>
> This will instruct the linker to not link against unused libraries. In
>   your example code, the C++ library is not used, so it should not link
>   against the C++ standard library.

Comment: It works! Thank  you for your help!!!  I follow the link and modify my test code, then it no more depend libstdc++ and test all right. Just one line in include list I removed: "#include <iostream>".  I cannot understand why just include head file force me to link libstdc++. and even confuse why libstdc++ must allocate memory when startup.The memory is completely out of control. This is really a bad experience.

Comment: `iostream` is the header for the c++ standard i/o. As per example: `cout` is defined inside the libstdc++.